# How do i update multiple sqlite data in recycler view?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I have a merchantList CARDVIEW. when i click a UPDATE button in the CARDVIEW it gets all data for that specific merchantand go to another screen which screen is also a CARDVIEW. Then i want to update all data and press a SINGLE UPDATE button to update all the row. How do i do this? I am using RecyclerVie and adapter.This is second screen . Each field is edit text. I want to edit and click the update assign button so that all data gets updated in sqlite
[image]

This is my java class 
    package com.example.user.paperflyv0;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UpdateAssigns extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView_ua;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager_ua;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter_ua;
    List<UpdateAssign_Model> updateAssignModelList;
    Database database;
    Button button;
    String exu_name,counts;
    Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        database=new Database(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.update_assigns);
        updateAssignModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        TextView mName = findViewById(R.id.merchant_name_update);
        mName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("MERCHANTNAME"));
        final String merchantcode = getIntent().getStringExtra("MERCHANTCODE");


        recyclerView_ua = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_ua);
        recyclerView_ua.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager_ua = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView_ua.setLayoutManager(layoutManager_ua);
        getData(merchantcode);



    }

    private void getData(final String merchantcode)
    {
        try{

            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = database.getassignedexecutive(sqLiteDatabase,merchantcode);
            while (c.moveToNext())
            {
                String name = c.getString(0);
                String count = c.getString(1);
                UpdateAssign_Model updateAssign_model = new UpdateAssign_Model(name,count);
                updateAssignModelList.add(updateAssign_model);
            }
            adapter_ua = new UpdateAssignsAdapter(updateAssignModelList,getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView_ua.setAdapter(adapter_ua);

            }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "some error" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my adapter -

```
package com.example.user.paperflyv0;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class UpdateAssignsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UpdateAssignsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   private List<UpdateAssign_Model> updateAssignModelList;
   private Context context;
   Button button;





    public UpdateAssignsAdapter(List<UpdateAssign_Model> updateAssignModelList,Context context) {
        this.updateAssignModelList = updateAssignModelList;
        this.context=context;

    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public AutoCompleteTextView itemExe;
        public EditText itemCount;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemExe = (AutoCompleteTextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.auto_complete);
            itemCount = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_count);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public UpdateAssignsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.update_assigns_layout, viewGroup, false);
        UpdateAssignsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new UpdateAssignsAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UpdateAssignsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        UpdateAssign_Model updateAssign_model = updateAssignModelList.get(i);
        viewHolder.itemExe.setText(updateAssign_model.getEx_name());
        viewHolder.itemCount.setText(updateAssign_model.getCount());
        /*viewHolder.itemCount.setTag(R.id.order_count,i);*/
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return updateAssignModelList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking for logic? If then First populate the items in recycler view with data from data base. them make changes in each row. and simultaneously save that data in model. Now when you press update button take the ArrayList of model and save it to DB. After saving move to next page and populate it.

Comment: The screen i've given here is the screen where i already populated my data from database in recycler view. how do i save the data in model? by set function?

Comment: List<UpdateAssign_Model> updateAssignModelList. This is your model right? On editing the particular editText, please update "updateAssign_model.getCount()" for that particular item position by using text change listener for edit text for each item in the list.   - by set function itesef

Comment: Can you help me with any kind of code?

Comment: all row of that particulay merchandiser_id

Comment: The name and the count which is showing. i want to update both field.

Comment: yes they are the row of the same table.

Comment: these are multiple row in one table according to one merchantcode.

Comment: I am storing name, count and the common merchantcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    viewHolder.itemCount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int count, int after) {
       }

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int before, int count) {
// IF YOU USE HANDLER HERE IT WILL BE MORE EFFICIENT
         updateAssign_model.setCount();
       }
      });
```

Place this code inside your adapter

Comment: Thank you so much. And how do i update all row with the new data to the Sqlite database?

Comment: Please go through update/ insert data to database and update your SQLiteDatabase whit all data from the "List<UpdateAssign_Model> updateAssignModelList".